# Registration confirmation php

Tags: php, html, email, web, registration

When a person registers to my website, I am trying to add the registration to the database and then email them a confirmation. The database add works, but my program doesn't email them. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
</head>  
<body>  
<div id="main">

<?php
{
  include "base.php"; //connect to database
  if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['email']);
    $password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['password']));
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['firstName']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['lastName']);
    $addressline1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['addressLine1']);
    $addressline2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['addressLine2']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['city']);
    $county = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['county']);
    $postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['postCode']);
    $phoneno = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['base'], $_POST['phoneNo']);

    $checkemail = mysqli_query($_SESSION['base'], "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email =   '".$email."'");
  }

  if(mysqli_num_rows($checkemail) == 1) {
?>
         <h1>Register</h1>

                <p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

                <form action='register.php' method='post' name='registerform' id='registerform'>
                    <label for='email'>Email:</label><input type='text' name='email' id='email' /><br />
                    <label for='password'>Password:</label><input type='password' name='password' id='password' /><br />
                    <label for='firstname'>First Name:</label><input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName' /><br />
                    <label for='lastname'>Last Name:</label><input type='text' name='lastName' id='lastName' /><br />
                    <label for='addressline1'>Address Line 1:</label><input type='text' name='addressLine1' id='addressLinel' /><br />
                    <label for='addressline2'>Address Line 2:</label><input type='text' name='addressLine2' id='addressLine2' /><br />
                    <label for='city'>City:</label><input type='text' name='city' id='city' /><br />
                    <label for='county'>County:</label><input type='text' name='county' id='county' /><br />
                    <label for='postcode'>Postcode:</label><input type='text' name='postCode' id='postCode' /><br />
                    <label for='phoneno'>Phone no:</label><input type='text' name='phoneNo' id='phoneNo' /><br />
                    <input type='submit' name='register' id='register' value='Register' />
                </form>
                <?php
    echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
    echo "<p>Sorry, that Email is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
}
else
{
    $registerquery = mysqli_query($_SESSION['base'], "INSERT INTO Users (Email, Password,   FirstName, LastName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, County, PostCode, PhoneNo) 
    VALUES('".$email."', '".$password."', '".$firstname."', '".$lastname."',  '".$addressline1."', '".$addressline2."', '".$city."', '".$county."', '".$postcode."', '".$phoneno."')");
    if($registerquery)
{
$to = "email";
$subject = "Email Verification mail";
$headers = "From: cameron@abandoned \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: cameron@abandoned.com \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message.='<div style="width:550px; background-color:#CC6600; padding:15px; font-    weight:bold;">';
$message.='Email Verification mail';
$message.='</div>';
$message.='<div style="font-family: Arial;">Confiramtion mail have been sent to your email     id<br/>';
$message.='hello cameron ';
$message.='</div>';
$message.='</body></html>';

mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
}

        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a    href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";

    }
    else
    {   
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please enter your details again.   </p>";
    }       
}
}
else{
?>
<h1>Register</h1>

 <p>Please enter your details below to register.</p>

    <form action='register.php' method='post' name='registerform' id='registerform'>
        <label for='email'>Email:</label><input type='text' name='email' id='email' /><br />
        <label for='password'>Password:</label><input type='password' name='password' id='password' /><br />
        <label for='firstname'>First Name:</label><input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName' /><br />
        <label for='lastname'>Last Name:</label><input type='text' name='lastName' id='lastName' /><br />
        <label for='addressline1'>Address Line 1:</label><input type='text' name='addressLine1' id='addressLinel' /><br />
        <label for='addressline2'>Address Line 2:</label><input type='text' name='addressLine2' id='addressLine2' /><br />
        <label for='city'>City:</label><input type='text' name='city' id='city' /><br />
        <label for='county'>County:</label><input type='text' name='county' id='county' /><br />
        <label for='postcode'>Postcode:</label><input type='text' name='postCode' id='postCode' /><br />
        <label for='phoneno'>Phone no:</label><input type='text' name='phoneNo' id='phoneNo' /><br />
        <input type='submit' name='register' id='register' value='Register' />
    </form>
<?php
?>
<html>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you developing on a local server like WAMP or MAMP?

Comment: you shouldn't be storing your DB handle in the session. That's pointless.  As for the email, did you check the return value from the mail() call. If it's false, then PHP can't even hand the email off to the delivery system. If it's true, then check your mail server's logs to see what happened to the email after PHP handed it off.

Comment: You need a valid `from` address that points to the server you're sending from. That's the most important prerequisite.

Comment: A few things: you need to provide the smallest code sample possible that replicates the problem, and _then_ ask the question: the process of doing this will and trimming down the huge block of code you've provided will  help you figure out how this is working. Secondly, are you seeing error messages in /var/logs/https/error_log or wherever your log files are stored? Errors are important! If you're not able to access those instrument your code to put errors directly on your webpage.

Comment: have you checked if mail is working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to email from your own webserver, with localhost and all that? Because if you want to send an email you'll need to have a mailserver aswell. For me, I dont't want a locally  mailserver so I creates the function and test it on the prodserver for the site.

Comment: Im just trying to email my hotmail account, so it will be and external web server

Comment: From your local server? That doesn't work. You'll need to configure Apache with a mailserver (SMTP server).

You can read a little bit more here: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/3403-how-to-use-email-with-apache-and-php-on-localhost/